# drawLine using AWT

Tags: java, awt

I just started with GUI using AWT. The frame is opening but the Line is not being displayed.

[image: frame image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class A extends Frame
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Frame f= new Frame();
        f.setTitle("New Frame");
        f.setSize(1000,1000);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we){System.exit(0);}});

    }
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.drawLine(60,500,230,5);
    }
}
```

Comment: AWT is quite dated, newer is java swing, and yet newer is JavaFX. Swing is most near to awt and still in heavy use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating a Frame object, not an `A` object, and so your paint method is never called.

Instead of

```
Frame a = new Frame();
```

try

```
A a = new A();
```

Side comment: your paint method override should call the super's method within it.

Having said this, why are you using AWT, a library that has now been superseded by not one but **two** newer graphics libraries, first Swing and now JavaFx? AWT is beyond dead at this point.